# Combined switch for microcontroller power and reset

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, switches, reset

I have a microcontroller that is powered by a battery.
I wish to use a single switch to either reset the microcontroller OR to power it off.
Is there a simple way to combine both functions in one switch?

I though about using a OFF-ON-MOM sliding switch where the center position would enable the power supply and the rightmost position is a momentary position to trigger the reset. However, I am unable to find a switch that keeps the power on when triggering the momentary reset position. A switch like [JS207011CQNR](https://www.ckswitches.com/media/1422/js.pdf) would disable the power supply when moving to the momentary position. Using the second pin on the momentary position as additional power supply also does not seem to work as the switch is marked as "non shortening" which would therefore shortly interrupt the power supply.

Obviously I could use two separate switches as alternative, but one combined switch would lead to a cleaner case design.

Is there a specific name for a switch that would not interrupt the center position, or are such non-breaking switches generally rare?
Or are there other alternative solutions?

Comment: how do you reset a microcontroller that you disconnected from power? Doesn't disconnecting already reliably lead to a reset?

Comment: How do you power off a microcontroller ? As for reset, all uCs i've worked with have a dedicated reset pin that resets the controller when grounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a range of ways that this could be done.
Here is one. It may suggest others that better suit you.

SW2 operated turns on FET M1 via D1, and
turns off M2, allowing Reset to be pulled high elsewhere.

When SW2 is released

- /RESET is instantly asserted low.
- M1 is held on by C1 until discharged by R1.

If SW2 is re-operated before M1 turns off then only reset operation occurs.

Adding hysteresis would probably be wise.
A PNP transistor could be used for M1 with a suitable pulldown resistor added.
A package of Schmitt inverters would perform the same logic task with sharp on/off switching action.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGwMsp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Note:

Edited to replace M2 with an NFET - had ben an NPN transistor.
D1 should be a silicon diode, NOT Schottky (so that diode leakage does not 'compete' with R2 'pullup').

Comment: Was Q1 meant to be NMOS?

Comment: @TimWilliams  Q1 (reset line) COULD be NMOS but works OK with a jellybean NPN as shown. It doesn't need the usual series base resistor as R2 effectively fills that role. Sw2 turns it off hard. R2 turns it on well enough. || If I was doing this I'd probably use a package of Schmitt inverters for the "logic". Costs more, More PCB space. Works well.  OR add hysteresis to M1. Which may be annoying. || This is meant as an idea starter. It would probably work as is. Having anti-brownout in the uC is highly desirable - BUT, it always is. I would never use a uC without brownout and low Vdd management.

Comment: I was thinking M1 never turns off (check Vbe), and R2's idle current will be rather high for battery operation.

Comment: @TimWilliams  Yes/Doh! :-) . Excuse: Early hours of morning :-). Ad yes, a FET will fix that.  Edited. Thanks